# Designing issue in JSP and servlets

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am doing my college minor project using JSP, servlets and Tomcat, I found some issues to my design.

Problem: My design changes always when I reload the page in browser although I have not made any change in CSS or any JSP code, if I open the same file from Dreamweaver than its shows the required design. Could you please help me regarding this issues?

```
login.css
    body {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: url(../images/bg.png) 0 64px repeat-x;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
        xmargin: 0 auto;
    }

    #border-top.h_green {
        background: url(../images/j_header_middle.png) repeat-x;
        height: 84px;
        xmargin: 0 auto;
    }

    #contentbox,#header-top {
        width: 755px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        xbackground: #efefef;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #menuheader {
        position: relative;
    }

    #contentbox p {
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    #menubox {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border-left: 1px solid #cccecc;
        border-right: 1px solid #cccecc;
        height: 15px;
    }

    #user_name {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        xbackground: url(../../../images/icons/user.png) no-repeat scroll 0 2px
            transparent;
        padding-left: 20px;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #666;
    }

    .loginwrapper {
        width: 755px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .btn{ 
        background:url(../images/btn.jpg) repeat-x;
        height:28px;
        border:none;
        color:#fff;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    .loginbox {
        background: url(../images/login_shadow.png) no-repeat;
        height: 310px;
        padding: 40px;
    }

    .rightsection {
        width: 85%;
        float: right;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cccc;
    }

    .rightboxwrapper {
        float: left;
        width: 325px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        background: url(../images/loginleft.png) no-repeat center bottom;
        height: 262px;
    }

    .rightboxwrapper .loginheader h2 {
        color: #0588ab;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: trebuchet MS;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .loginform input {
        width: 170px;
    }

    .loginform input#btnsubmit {
        width: 80px !important;
        border: none;
    }

    .loginform {
        padding: 10px 0 0 45px;
        line-height: 35px;
        background: url(../images/lock.png) no-repeat right center;
        width: 335px;
    }

    .loginform td {
        color: #333333;
        font-family: trebuchet MS;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .copyright {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        font-size: 11px;;
        color: #0588ab;
        font-family: trebuchet MS;
    }

    .copyright p {
        padding-right: 15px !important;
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn the HTML/CSS first. Please buy some good books (never use w3schools, dreamweaver etc), use simple text editors or IDE like netbeans, eclipse etc).

Comment: Are you running the jsp page on tomcat ? Running jsp on browser directly will not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons i can think of:

1. You forgot to link the page to the css.
2. The css is not loaded (probably because of wrong url), you can check this by right clicking the page  and choosing 'view source', then find the css url at the top and click it to see if you are getting it.

It would be helpfull if you post the jsp/css.

Comment: AurA: I am using tomcat 6 for running jsp page. My problem is that design is not working properly. But sometime when i run  its works fine again if i refresh the browser logo will be disappear itself.

Comment: how to upload css file?can you give your email add where i can send whole project.

Comment: just edit your question and copy paste the relevant text, but make sure to put it as code (on the top use the curley brackets)

Comment: sorry i could not upload css file,\

Comment: ftom2 here is css file...could you please check if there is any error?

Comment: Did you perform what i offered at section 2?

Comment: ftom2 yes i did it, it show a link of css file that i have kept.

Comment: Did you press the link? When you pressed it, did you see the css?